# c# Android Xamarin - Crash while using TextView.Text with ElapsedEventHandler

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

My app crashs when I call the `Print` function while I am using `System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(checkForMessage)`.

I called the `Print` function in other contexts and there was no problem.

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace Ev3BtCom
{
    [Activity(Label = "Ev3BtCom", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        Ev3Messaging _ev3Messaging = new Ev3Messaging();

        bool isParsing = true;
        TextView infosLabel;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            ...
            infosLabel = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Infos);

            _ev3Messaging = new Ev3Messaging();


            System.Timers.Timer checkForTime = new System.Timers.Timer(500);
            checkForTime.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(checkForMessage);
            checkForTime.Enabled = true;



            connectBut.Click += async (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                bool error = false;
                try
                {
                    await _ev3Messaging.Connect(brickNameET.Text);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Print(ex.Message);
                    error = true;
                }
                if(!error)
                {
                    Print("Connected");
                    isParsing = false;
                }
            };

            ...//Many use of the print function in the same context WITHOUT CRASH
        }

        async void checkForMessage(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!isParsing)
            {
                isParsing = true;
                byte[] datas = new byte[0];
                try
                {
                    datas = await _ev3Messaging.ReceiveText();
                }catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    await _ev3Messaging.SendText("Text", ex.Message);
                    Print(ex.Message);   // MAKES APP CRASH
                }
                if (datas.Length != 0)
                {
                    string printedText = "Received: ";
                    foreach (byte b in datas)
                        printedText += (int)b + ",";
                    Print(printedText);    // MAKES APP CRASH
                    await _ev3Messaging.SendText("Text", printedText);
                }
                Print("Test");   // MAKES APP CRASH
                isParsing = false;
            }
        }

        void Print(string text)
        {
            infosLabel.Text += text + "\n"; // When I remove this line, there is no more crash
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the Exception / StackTrace?

Comment: There is no displayed Exception, the app is closed without any message... And sorry, I am a beginner, and I don't know what you mean with "StackTrace"...

Comment: You can find a trace in your `adb logcat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timer.Elapsed event is always queued for execution on a thread pool thread so you need to make sure that you update the UI controls on the UI thread. To achieve that, you can use the RunOnUiThread method like so:

```
void Print(string text)
{
    RunOnUiThread(() => infosLabel.Text += text + "\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It worked ! I am learning to program with Xamarin and I never heard about RunOnUiThread before...

Comment: Glad to hear that. You'll likely bump into many obscure problems like this one in the future, but don't give up. There's always a sensible explanation for why something's not working.